# CIFilterGenerator filename extension

Tags: macos, core-image, uti

Is there an expected UTI or filename extension for generated Core Image filters exported using [CIFilterGenerator's `writeToURL:atomically:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CIFilterGenerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CIFilterGenerator/writeToURL%3aatomically%3a)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, extension ".cifilter".

If you save one of these out to /Library/Graphics/Image Units/, it'll get picked up if it has that extension.